# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in React-natibve-branch with the error "framework not found React"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

using pods for only react-native-branch got this error : 
Directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React'

but with manual installation, it gives the error in

Comment: Have you tried pod install? If yes clean and build the project and try. What is the RN version that you are using?

Comment: yes, i've already did it. but still getting the same error